# What's the magic behind CAReplicatorLayer?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, quartz-core, careplicatorlayer

What I find interesting with CAReplicatorLayer:

- It is able to display a CALayer multiple times with different transforms very efficiently (how?)
- It seems like it somehow reuses the "backing store" for the replicated layer and even apply some color tints to it (how?)

I would like to get hands on either the source code or get some knowledge of the magic behind CAReplicatorLayer. I would like to have a CALayer class similar to CAReplicatorLayer, but with more control. I would like to **have control on the transform** individually **for each replicated instance**.

So asked in a totally different manner: 
is it possible to get the "backing store" for a CALayer and display it however I want as many times I want?

(by "backing store" I mean the rendered texture for the CALayer/UIView. I don't know much about what's happening under the hoods of CoreAnimation/QuartzCore).

---

Why I'm not looking at alternatives like e.g. rendering the CALayer to a UIImage:

- Performance
- Content is dynamic/changing pretty frequently under the transitions
- It would be hands down awesome to do it the other way!

Comment: Been wondering this myself. Hope someone smarter than us comes along haha.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The special-purpose CALayers like CAReplicatorLayer or CAGradientLayer are able (via private APIs) do execute their drawing directly on the GPU using fast filling or copying. In a sense they are different such that the backing store is not in normal RAM, but directly on the GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That does not sound promising for what I was hoping to do, but indeed clarifies some aspects. :)

Comment: you can always use an EAGLLayer and draw on that with OpenGL with shaders. This would be the fasted way to do custom drawing.

Comment: I suppose I can't do that backed by UIViews? Or in my case: I'm doing something as bold as replicating a UIWebView. I would very much like something similar to CAReplicatorLayer, but with control over each individual instance' transform (instead of the incremental one CAReplicatorLayer offers). If OpenGL/EAGLLayer offers that I would be more than happy.